# Getting "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded" when editing a TableView cell

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I'm trying to track down an error I get when editing a `QTableView` cell. Every time I edit an element I get the following:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Exactly 7 times, every time. It still works but if I keep editing it eventually locks and I can no longer edit anything (as this errors pile up).

I'm assuming this is on my setData() function since it's right when I finish editing the cell.

```
def setData(self, index, value, role = Qt.EditRole):
    if role == Qt.EditRole:
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()
        item = value
        self.__shots[row][column] = item
        self.dataChanged.emit(index,index)
        return True
    return False
```

During my research I only found this about QModelIndex() ([here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html)):

> When reimplementing this function in a subclass, be careful to avoid
>   calling QModelIndex member functions, such as QModelIndex::parent(),
>   since indexes belonging to your model will simply call your
>   implementation, leading to infinite recursion.

I understand I use index in the setData() but not so sure if this is related or how to fix it. I'm new to Model View and have been learning mostly from [Yasin Uludag's blog](http://www.yasinuludag.com/blog/).

Comment: setData() looks ok to me. Are you sure the error is not coming from somewhere else?

Comment: Hey @TimHoffmann, it's my first guess since I get the errors right when I press enter do commit to the changes on the cell. Nothing before or after. There's nothing mentioning recursion in the documentation on Qt's website (http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#setData)

Comment: do you have any slots bould to `dataChanged` that may induce another update?

Comment: I have one more used of dataChanged() on data():

`def data(self, index, role):
  """Keeps the data in the cell when in edit mode."""
  if role == Qt.EditRole:
   row = index.row()
   column = index.column()

   self.__shots[row][column]
   self.dataChanged.emit(index,index)`

Comment: `data()` is for reading values from the model (http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#data). There should never be a need to emit `dataChanged` here. Instead you should `return self.__shots[row][column]`

Comment: Wow, @TimHoffmann, that was awesome. It works flawlessly now. Thank you so much for your help, I've been breaking my head over this for a few days :D

Answer (score 0):

You'll find that in the comments @TimHoffmann asked me if I had another instance of `dataChanged()` and it turns out I was using it inside `data()`, causing the recursion problem.